# How to populate img src with event.target.files before saving image to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postgresql

I'm saving images to a files object which I'm then using that object to save to the server.

**(ReactJS)**

```
onChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      file: event.target.files[0],
      loaded: 0,
    });
  }

onClickHandler = () => {
    const { match: { params} } = this.props;
    const data = new FormData()
    console.log(this.state.file)
    data.append('file', this.state.file)
    axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/albums/${params.albumId}/upload`, data, {

    }).then(res => {
      console.log(res.statusText)
    })
  }
```

**(NodeJS - image-upload.js)**

```
const getImageByAlbumId = (request, response) => {
  const { id }  = request.params;

  db.pool.query('SELECT * FROM file WHERE album_id = $1 ORDER BY album_id ASC', [id], (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    } else {
    response.status(200).json(results.rows)
    console.log("getImageByAlbumId " + JSON.stringify(request.params));
   }
  })
}


const imageUpload = (req, res) => {
    var id = parseInt(req.params.id);
    message: "Error! in image upload."
     if (!req.file) {
          console.log("No file recieved");
          message = "Error! in image upload."
          console.log("status: danger");
     } else {
        console.log('file recieved');
        console.log(req.file);

         var query = db.pool.query('INSERT INTO file (name, type, size, path, album_id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) ON CONFLICT (album_id) DO NOTHING RETURNING *', [req.file.filename, req.file.mimetype, req.file.size, req.file.path, id], (err, result) => {
            console.log('inserted data')
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
               console.log('inserted data')
               console.log(result)
         }
         });
         message = "Successfully uploaded";
         console.log("status: success");
     }

}
```

**(NodeJS - index.js)**

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'public')
    }, 
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, Date.now() + '-' +file.originalname)
    }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));
app.use(upload.single('file'));

app.get('/albums/:id/images', image.getImageByAlbumId)
app.post('/albums/:id/upload', image.imageUpload);
```

I'm using that file that I saved to my server which in hand saved a path to my database using `req.file.path`. And then adding that path to my state when `componentDidMount()`. I'm then trying to use that path to use for the img src.

```
<img style={{ width: "300px", height: "300px"}} src={this.props.file[0].path} />
```

My issue is that if nothing is loaded to the server yet I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined`. Also I'm trying to load the image into the src when the user clicks on that image so they can view the image on the front-end before they save it to the database and have to reload the page.

So I'm wondering how I can load that image in the src with I guess `event.target.files[0]` before reloading the page/ retrieving the file from the database but also using the image from the database when it's reloaded or saved to the database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There isn't a `path` property on File objects. What you need to do to render the selected file is use [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL).

For example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState();
  const onChange = e => setImage(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="file" onChange={onChange} />
      {image && <img src={image} alt="The current file" />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Check this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-franklin-kgr2o) for an example

Comment: I can do this but what do I save to my server. I don't think I can save `URL.createObjectURL()` type to my server.

Comment: Assuming that the file upload portion of this is currently working - your `onClickHandler` already handles that doesn't it? Add a separate state variable in your `onChange` to set the <img /> src per my example.

Comment: I added an extra variable for my image before the save and it worked

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad you got it working. Please accept my answer if you think it helped you get there.